# Optimizing WPF Add-In Activation

Tags: wpf, add-in, maf

Are there any optimization tricks for activating a WPF Add-In?  My current AddIn activates in roughly 5-6 seconds but because it is being loaded on the UI thread, the UI is blocked for this duration.  I am trying to simply display a progress bar  but it will never update because of the UI blocking.  I implemented a simple hack that starts a thread, waits 2 seconds and then loads the AddIn through the Dispatcher.  This solution is decent but after two seconds the progress bar freezes.